# cakephp edit action and requests?

Tags: php, cakephp, request, response, edit

So can someone explain this to me?
 I'm trying to write an edit action and am a bit unsure of why the following does not work:

```
public function edit($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException('NO ID HAS BEEN SUPPLIED');
    } 

    $data = $this->User->findById($id); 

    if(!$this->request->is('post')) { $this->request->data = $data;   }


    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) { 
       $this->User->id = $id; 
       $this->User->save($this->request->data);
       $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
   } 
}
```

And by not working, I mean, that while it does pre-populate the form with data gathered from findById($id).. it doesn't update the database with the new inputs after the form has been sent.

I have replaced this:

```
if(!$this->request->is('post'))
```

With the following:

```
if($this->request->is('get'))
```

And suddenly, it works fine. It updates the row with the new values gathered from the post. However, I do not understand what's happening here. Why is it that  !$this->request->is('post),  does NOT work, while $this->request->is('get') DOES work?
Surely, when the action is first called it is called using a GET request? Doesn't that request qualify as !$this->request->is('post')?

EDIT:

below is the ctp: app/View/Users/edit.ctp

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>

     <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('edit User'); ?></legend>

    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->input('role');
   // echo $this->Form->input('role', array(
     //   'options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'regular' => 'Regular')
    //));//
?>
</fieldset> <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Comment: can you provide link from ctp file and url from Routs?

Comment: Why don't you just bake the controller (and optionally view) so you see what the standard way is? Your method for saving lacks a call to exists for example. The standard solution you don't have to write by yourself is better. Then you can enhance it to specific needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Cake uses 'PUT' method for 'edit' action and 'POST' for 'add'. so you need to check `$this->request->isPut()` (or `$this->request->is('put')`). Look for a hiiden field *_method* that automatically generated by `$this->Form->create()` method in your view.

If 'id' property is set in data passed to view Cake creates 'edit' form and 'add' if no 'id'.

Comment: I did not know that. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
public function edit() {
$id = $this->params['id'];
if (!$id) {
    throw new NotFoundException('NO ID HAS BEEN SUPPLIED'); } 

   $data = $this->User->findById($id); 

   if(!$this->request->is('post')) { $this->request->data = $data;   }


    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) { 

$this->User->id = $id; 
$this->User->save($this->request->data);
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));}
```

passing id to edit from url is not safe way... `$this->params['id']` will have your post id so 
with it `$this->request->is('put')` will work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out.What does params do if I may ask?

Comment: it will do same as $this->request->is('POST') do

Comment: thanks. tried running your code as is. It doesn't seem to work. I get a ' Error: The requested address '/www/users/edit/1' was not found on this server.' when I try and access the row. Any idea?

Comment: can you please provide link from ctp file and router?

Comment: Edited my post with the ctp file including location. I have checked my route file, I haven't done anything to it since installation. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Router::connect('/<Location>',array('controller'=>'YourController','action'=>'action','id'=>'[0-9]+')); in router

$this->Html->link('Edit',array('controller'=>'controller',action=>'edit',$id));

$id might be like $User['User']['id']; just don't make ur like this
$this->Html->link('Edit',array('controller'=>'controller',action=>'edit','id'=>$id));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890464/cakephp-fields-not-populating-in-edit-screen?rq=1

Have a look at it if you didn't get what I mean

Comment: Thank you! I'll see how it goes.